# Classifying degenerate stationary points with the Hessian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

I've been wondering about the test to classify stationary points using the Hessian matrix. In the 2 variable case, things are fairly easy to deal with, I'm concerned with 3 or more variables. I've been told that when the Hessian is positive/negative definite, the stationary point is a minimum/maximum. Those make sense.

I've also been told that if all the eigenvalues are non-zero, and not all the same sign, then the point is a saddle point. Again, makes sense.

My problem is the next bit - supposedly, if any eigenvalue is zero, we must check higher order derivatives to be sure about the nature of the point. However, say we had a stationary point for a 3 variable function, for which one eigenvalue of the Hessian is 0, but the others differ in sign. Intuitively, I read that as meaning along one "principal direction", the curvature is flat, and along the others the curve is convex/concave. While I can't actually visualise this, it very much seems like a saddle point to me, given the curving in different directions. My question is whether that intuition holds any water, or if my understanding of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the Hessian isn't quite up to scratch?

To clarify, my knowledge of the Hessian is minimal (found out about it today), but I've read that the eigenvectors tell you the directions of principal curvature, and in the case of a 2 variable function, and its corresponding 3-dimensional surface, this just means the directions of maximal and minimal curvature. Because this case is 3 dimensional, there's no issue, since I can visualise all the situations, and there's no capacity for an ambiguous situation like the one I mentioned to arise.

Comment: Yes, what you said is correct: If the eigenvalues are negative, $0$, and positive, then the critical point is a saddle point. But what if they are $0$ and positive? Or $0$ and negative?

Comment: @TedShifrin I suppose those cases are more vague, and you'd need higher order information, which is fine. The main bit I was concerned about was if having eigenvalues of differing sign was sufficient for a saddle point, even in the presence of eigenvalues that are zero, since most sources I've read so far say the 0 case is always inconclusive.

Comment: Yup, correct. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Correct about it always being inconclusive, or correct in the differing signs being sufficient for saddle points? If it's the latter, I suppose that's problem solved.

Comment: Both, of course.

Comment: @TedShifrin Well, now I'm confused. How can the test always be inconclusive given some 0 eigenvalue, if you say it's conclusive for one negative, one 0, one positive? Isn't it only inconclusive if you have all eigenvalues non-negative/non-positive (with at least one being 0)?

Comment: Precisely, yes. That is what I meant by what I wrote in my very first comment.